# how can pass argument to java script from vb?

Tags: javascript, vb.net

i am Writing a simple code to add 2 no. I declare the variable in java script and give argument from vb.
 in Script part

```
enter code here
function javascriptFunction() {
var x;
var y;
var z = x + y;
alert(z);
```

and in Vb part i write

```
enter code here
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("javascriptFunction", _
New String() {"2", "3"})
End Sub
```

i am new In javascript.So plz any suggestion

Comment: A few observations: 1.) Not java script, but javascript. 2.) How do you want to pass a value to javascript from a different language?

Comment: @SimoEndre It's possible because he forgot to tell that he's invoking js inside a WebBrowser control in .Net Winforms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your javascript function doesn't receive any parameters as it's declared now. It should be declared as:

```
function javascriptFunction(x, y) {
    var z = x + y;
    alert(z);
}
```

Comment: @SimoEndre Why not? He's passing the params correctly, but there isn't any js function that match with those parameters right now.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4b1a88bz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: It is working .. The result shows as string...@ Simo